# simplest way to get time difference between program start and program start producing output in linux?

Tags: linux, command, pipe, stdout

I need to know the time difference between binary start and it's first output to stdout in linux. 
Is there a simple way to find it using bash command line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

E.g., you can use `ts` tool from `moreutils` package:

```
$ echo hello | ts -i                
00:00:00 hello

$ ( sleep 3 && echo hello ) | ts -i
00:00:03 hello
```

Comment: perfect. only note is output i have was binary video, so i had to use 'command | head -c1 | ts -i' to examine the timestamp instead of insane amounts of binary flow. thanks!